# Selenium Webdriver change screenshot preferences

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

Or "NOT taking an entire page screenshot"

**According to the documentation about screenshots**

The driver makes a best effort to return a screenshot of the following, in order of preference:

1. Entire page
2. Current window
3. Visible portion of the current frame
4. The screenshot of the entire display containing the browser

Is there any way to configure Selenium or pass an argument to [takeScreenshot](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#858) skip the "entire page" option?

Most of the time I'd prefer less screenshot to more, and given that the entire page functionality is inconsistent across different browsers, I'd rather bypass the "best effort at entire page" entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave this open a bit longer just in case anyone knows different, but it seems there isn't a way to set your preference and that taking a screenshot is "officially" and intentionally the entire page unless that fails, per https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5332 etc.